# How to enhance neo4j batch insertion?

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

I have an Oracle DB of roughly 20 million record. I used the BatchInserter to insert the data in my model.
The problem is that I have to loop over a result set containing the whole 20 million data to get the needed properties to insert. But it take too long time to do just the loop process.

Anyone tried something like that? and What is the best way to do it in an optimum time?

Comment: Divide-and-Conquer. Split the import process into multiple chunks and run each of them in parallel. –

Comment: Unfortunately I tried it, i divide my query to more queries to get less data and run it in threads, but it still takes more time than expected

Comment: Just curious, how much time does it take ? and what's the time you're expecting ?

Comment: It takes roughly 45 min to insert 2 million db record.. I read before that it may take just seconds or max few mins

Answer (score 1):

Can you share more details? Where do you have to loop?

Check http://neo4j.org/develop/import for some options.

If you have JDBC you can also drive the import directly from your JDBC results.

Just loop twice over the results, once for nodes and once for rels.

Comment: I'm getting my data using JDBC, and so I have to loop over the returned resultset as follows :
`while (resultRows.next()) {`
`Long someId = resultRows.getLong(1);
Long someId2 = resultRows.getLong(2);
`
and do this to get more than 17 propereties, and then add this properties to the node.. and exactly that loop is what make the long execution time